# VBA-HTML Dropdown list selecting value on drop down

Tags: vba, web, dom, automation, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a tool that opens this Web page dialog box that consists of a table that haswhen executed it will populate this object and hit a button to close the dialog box, however It seems it's not selecting physically the value from combo box. I've tried .SelectedIndex and .innerText but still when I hit the button to exit it still prompts me that I still haven't selected the data for this combo box. FOr example the combo box has values of "Select data", "Data 1" and "Data 2", of course upon opening the web page dialog box the default value of this combo box is "Select data" and when I run the code which focuses, clicks and gives value to this combo box as "Data 1"(from the code) and hit the button it will still prompt me that I still haven't selected any data and the combo box value will go from my selected data "Data 1" to "Select Data" again. I hope I explained it thoroughly but If you have clarification just let me know. I can't provide the URl since this is a system from the company I am supporting.

Below is my execution code and HTML of the web page dialog box:

```
Public Sub completeReserveLog() 
Dim iRes_Html As HTMLDocument
AssResScr="the title page of the URL"
Set iRes_Html = HtmlDocFromHandleJex(AssResScr, "Reserves")
If iRes_Html Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
With iRes_Html
    'In this scenario is kinda confusing because I'm not really sure
        'if what is really the name of my combox object. So I used these two: mvASSOC1_0 and mvASSOC1_1_0
      .getElementById("mvASSOC1_1_0").Focus
      .getElementById("mvASSOC1_0").Value = 1
      .getElementById("mvASSOC1_1_0").Value = "Data 1"
      .getElementById("mvASSOC1_1_0").Click
End With
End Sub
```

HTML(I'll incude the code for the two objects I'm confudsed determining the true object.

```
<TD class=mvTD><INPUT onbeforeactivate=storeCurVal() onbeforedeactivate=checkCurVal() onfocus=showMVCBO() id=mvASSOC1_1_0 class=mvFieldStyle 

onkeydown=RowUpDown() style="TEXT-ALIGN: left; BACKGROUND-COLOR: white" ondrop=callBAFieldValidated() value="Data 1" eventParams="" 

validationName="Risk" decimals="" groupDigits="" cboName="mvASSOC1_0" max="" min="" validationType="text" keyfield="1" mandatory="0" code="1"></TD>

</TR></TBODY></TABLE></DIV></DIV><INPUT onchange=callBA() id=dbr3eportElement 

style="HEIGHT: 1px; WIDTH: 1px; POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 0px; DISPLAY: none; TOP: 0px" name=dbreportElement fieldType="text"><SPAN id=rdesignbaisdrop 

style="HEIGHT: 0px; WIDTH: 0px; POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 0px; Z-INDEX: 9999; DISPLAY: none; TOP: 0px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: transparent"         name="rdesignbaisdrop" 

fieldType="span">

</SPAN><SELECT onchange=hideshowMVCBO() onblur=hideMVCBO() id=mvASSOC1_0 class=mvFieldStyle onkeydown=hideMVCBO() style="WIDTH: 194px; 

POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 43px; DISPLAY: none; TOP: 82px; VISIBILITY: visible" mvhFlag="_1" currentDIV="mvASSOC1_1_0"><OPTION value="">---Select Data---

</OPTION><OPTION selected value=1>Data 1</OPTION><OPTION value=2>Data 2</OPTION><OPTION value=4>Data 4</OPTION><OPTION value=12>Data    12</OPTION></SELECT>
```

I hope this supplies all the needed data.

Comment: your select element is the one with id mvASSOC1_0 . Though this and the preceeding 2 input elements have a lot of events associated. You may need to explore if any of these need .FireEvent "nameOfEvent"  ....

Comment: I tried using that .FireEvent ("onchange") and still doesn't make any changes.

Comment: There are lots of events. Also, you may have more luck with using selenium basic.

Comment: Yeah. Selenium can't be an option since I'm working on a citrix server from a company and that could take a long time for approvals and installation to go through.

Comment: Might be worth exploring for the future

Comment: Hi, Anyone have an idea for this one?